# CFINDEX throwing attribute validation error exception

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am upgrading to ColdFusion 11 from ColdFusion 8, so I need to rebuild my search indices to work Solr instead of Verity. I cannot find any reliable way to import my old Verity collections, so I'm attempting to build the new indices from scratch. I am using the following code to index some items along with their corresponding documents which are located on the server:

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="3600" />

<cfquery name="qDocuments" datasource="#APPLICATION.DataSource#">
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ID,
        Status,
        'C:\Documents\'
            CONCAT ID
            CONCAT '.PDF'   AS  File
    FROM    tblDocuments
</cfquery>

<cfindex
    query="qDocuments"
    collection="solrdocuments"
    action="fullimport"
    type="file"
    key="document_file"
    custom1="ID"
    custom2="Status" />
```

A very similar setup was used with Verity for years without a problem.

When I run the above code, I get the following exception:

> Attribute validation error for CFINDEX.
>
> The value of the FULLIMPORT attribute is invalid. 
>       Valid values are: UPDATE, DELETE, PURGE, REFRESH, FULL-IMPORT, 
>          DELTA-IMPORT,STATUS, ABORT.

This makes absolutely no sense, since there is no "FULLIMPORT" attribute for CFINDEX.

I am running ColdFusion 11 Update 3 with Java 1.8.0_25 on Windows Server 2008R2/IIS7.5.

Comment: The error message you provided suggests that `full-import` (with a `-`) may be the action you want.

Comment: While sufficient to identify this problem, perhaps you might submit this as a bug as the text is misleading. Luckily the value unique among the code provided but another person might encounter  misleading text like this with a less-identifiable attribute. The error message should of course say something like `The value of the action attribute, 'fullimport' is invalid ...`

Comment: @Antony If you are suggesting that I user `full-import` as the value of the action attribute, I tried that, and it did not work - it returned an exception stating that the value was not valid.

Comment: so @EricBelair are you saying that neither `fullimport` as per the docs nor `full-import` as per the error message work? And that both `actions` generate the same error message? https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfindex doco link for those reviewing the question

Comment: @Antony the error message is stating that there is an attribute named `full-import` and the value I am using for it is invalid. however, if you look at the docs, you'll see that there is no `full-import` attribute. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should believe the error message. try this:

```
<cfindex
    query="qDocuments"
    collection="solrdocuments"
    action="FULL-IMPORT"
    type="file"
    key="document_file"
    custom1="ID"
    custom2="Status" />
```

It's referring to the *value* of the attribute *action*.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work, and throws a similar exception stating that the value of the action attribute is invalid. The documentation clearly states that "FULLIMPORT" is the value to be used.

Comment: Id say it sounds like a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a [bug](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4205226). In the ColdFusion documentation, fullimport is not an attribute of cfindex.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else has the same question, it's just poor descriptions in the documentation. The action "FullImport" is only available when using `type="dih"` (i.e. Data Import Handler). When using the `query` attributes, use `action="refresh"` instead.

[Source: CFIndex Documentation:](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfindex.html)

> ...
>    **When `type="dih"`, these actions are used:**
>
> - *abort*: Aborts an ongoing indexing task.
> - *deltaimport*: For partial indexing. For instance, for any updates in the database,
>     instead of a full import, you can perform delta import to update your
>     collection.
> - **fullimport**: To index full database. For instance,
>     when you index the database for the first time.
> - *status*:
>     Provides the status of indexing, such as the total number of documents
>     processed and status such as idle or running.